# Any way to synchronize window states of two side-by-side windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows

In windows you can do side by side by `win+left` or `win+right`. Say there are several windows opened along with a side-by-side windows pairs, when you switching (alt-tab) between, you always need to switch back both side-by-side windows to the front to continue to work in side-by-side state. When many windows are opened, alt-tab to the side-by-side pairs can be tiresome.

Is there anyway to synchronize both windows state such that when one of them is bring to front, bring another to front too?

Comment: ever thought about using something like "virtual workspaces"  (eg, http://dexpot.de/ )?

Comment: that's also the only solution I can think of

Answer (score 0):

@teylyn my apologies.
I new to this so...
anyways you use a task scheduler it has awesome feature of triggering events on the task go so you can use that.

for more visit [this](http://lifehacker.com/5932456/7-awesome-features-youve-forgotten-about-in-windows-7) link

Comment: what is the link? can you summarise the information

Comment: It shows how to add a task to task scheduler.